# How to write this data into xlsx file

Tags: excel, python-3.x, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from xlsxwriter import Workbook

ua = UserAgent()

header = {'user_agent':ua.chrome}

main_url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=laptop&_sacat=0'

page = requests.get(main_url, headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('div', class_='s-item__info clearfix')

for item in links:

    workbook = Workbook('Data.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write(0, 0, item.h3.text)
    worksheet.write(0, 1, item.a['href'].split('?')[0])
    worksheet.write(0, 2, item.div.next_sibling.next_sibling.text)
    worksheet.write(0, 3, item.div.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.text)
    worksheet.write(0, 4, item.find('span', class_='s-item__price').text)
    workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the script below. It should write the data in an excel file accrodingly. I almost change nothing in order to keep your basic structure intact. Make sure to change `IDK` according to it's appropriate header names.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xlsxwriter import Workbook
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
header = {'user_agent':ua.chrome}

workbook = Workbook('Data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(name="ItemList")

main_url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=laptop&_sacat=0'

page = requests.get(main_url, headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

#creating headers
bold = workbook.add_format({"bold":1})
worksheet.write("A1","Name",bold)
worksheet.write("B1","Link",bold)
worksheet.write("C1","IDK",bold)
worksheet.write("D1","IDK",bold)
worksheet.write("E1","Price",bold)

row = 1
col = 0

for item in soup.find_all('div', class_='s-item__info clearfix'):
    worksheet.write(row,col, item.h3.text)
    worksheet.write(row,col+1, item.a['href'].split('?')[0])
    worksheet.write(row,col+2, item.div.next_sibling.next_sibling.text)
    worksheet.write(row,col+3, item.div.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.text)
    worksheet.write(row,col+4, item.find('span',class_='s-item__price').text)
    row+=1

workbook.close()
```